# Cannot mount /dev/dm-2 . And filesystem for dm-2 shows empty

Tags: mount, filesystem, lvm

My server has /dev/dm-0 , /dev/dm-1, /dev/dm-2 . The first two could be mounted successfully while the third one fails with the message

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type .
```

dm-2 was working well until one day it became a read-only system (I have no idea why this could happen. I just cann't write any data into that disk). so I restart the server and now I cannot mount it anymore. Is there anyone who could give me a hint ? Below are some methods I have already tried. Thanks  !

So I typed command

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL 

NAME                                 FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT   LABEL
sr0                                               1024M            
sda                                                2.7T            
└─sda1                               LVM2_member   2.7T            
└─cv--storage-cv08_5T (dm-2)                     4.6T            
sdb                                                1.8T            
└─sdb1                               LVM2_member   1.8T            
└─cv--storage-cv08_5T (dm-2)                     4.6T            
sdc                                              465.8G            
├─sdc1                               ext4          953M /boot      
├─sdc2                               swap         18.6G [SWAP]      
├─sdc3                               ext4         74.5G /          
├─sdc4                                               1K             
└─sdc5                               LVM2_member 371.7G            
├─cv--storage-cv--workplace (dm-0)   ext4        180.7G            
└─cv--storage-hadoop (dm-1)          ext4          191G
```

I believe that there is something wrong with the filesystem of dm-2.
using

```
e2fsck -f /dev/dm-2
```

will show

```
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read 
while trying to open /dev/dm-2
Could this be a zero-length partition?

mkfs.ext4 /dev/dm-2
```

will show

```
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Warning: could not erase sector 2: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Filesystem label= 
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
152621056 inodes, 1220942848 blocks
61047142 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
37261 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
4096 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

Allocating group tables: done                            
Warning: could not read block 0: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Attempt to write block to filesystem resulted in short write
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:     1/37261
Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have found the answer: the hard disk is physically damaged.